# Should [strong] be a tag?

Tags: discussion

Recently there was an interesting question about the strongest drink in the world: [What is the strongest drink in the world?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6561/what-is-the-strongest-drink-in-the-world). The question has the tag [strong](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strong), which seems off to me.

While it's clear in the context of that one question, in general it just seems really vague as to what that tag means. The tag wiki could of course help, but since it is empty it isn't helping here at all. It also doesn't seem to me that even if defined a bit better it would create a useful tag, as it doesn't really add a significant grouping to this site. On top of all of that, there also aren't any other question with this same tag.

So should [strong](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strong) be a tag at all? If so what should it be about?

Comment: I agree, and my finger hovered over the "edit tags" link when I saw that question but, for reasons I can't remember, I didn't click it at the time.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, I left it out of this question because I didn't want to focus on that, but it might have something to do with the fact that I already removed the tag and the author added it back.

Comment: Why is it 'off' I believe it said exactly what I wanted it to say STRONG!  Can you please expand and enlighten me.

Comment: @dougal It's not the combination of the question with the tag that seems off, but the tag itself. I'm also using "off" as a synonym of "odd" here. The explanation for this in the next paragraph and some of it can also be found in the answers (which articulate things I had more trouble putting into words)

Comment: Per the general consensus, I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 6):

I'm also in favor of removing this tag.   Tags should be to help people find topics of interest, and I'm not sure how useful this particular tag is to that end.

Answer (score 2):

Let it be removed. Generally speaking, when one employs tags such as rum or whisky and the like, these imply a strong alcohol by their very nature.

Comment: **Comments deleted.** This isn't the place to discuss something that happened on another site.

Answer (score 1):

After being bounced around, and bouncing my own dougal head around and great comments from Jamie Eltringham, I agree!  Having sorted out my screen settings, I now see the advice on the right side bar!  New tags only dilute the site.